# Microsoft Word auto update included image

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I want to paste a big image into page one of a word document. Then I want to copy the same image to page two and crop it (so it only shows a section of the image).

I hope to achieve that if the big image changes I replace the big one and the cropped image updates to show the same section but with the updated content.

Since I have to display about 50+ sections of the same image in one word document I want to get rid of the process to manually update each image every time the big image changes. And I this also makes the word document a bit smaller than creating 50+ images and insert them one by one.

Is there any way to achieve this (preferably without scripting...)?
So far I have Word 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can come close to what you want with a Mapped Image Content Control copied into a Header or Footer

Here is a [temporary link to a sample document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ro6yfftwqaroq2p/deleteme%20image%20control.docx?dl=0) that demonstrates what I am talking about.

If you have a mapped image content control to insert your image, pasting a copy of that content control into the header/footer will mean that when the image is changed, it will change in both places. You can search this site or the Internet for information on mapping content controls. I used Greg Maxey's [Custom Content Control Insert Dialog Utility](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/Content_Control_Custom_Insert_Dialog.html) to create the mapped control but there are many ways available.

You would, after pasting into the header/footer, select different first page for the header/footer so that it will not appear twice on the first page.

The cropping though, would have to be done every time you change the image. That would be done in the header/footer, which now has the mapped copy.

### An alternative would be to simply insert the full image on the first page and paste a copy in the header/footer and crop it.

This would  give you a slightly larger file. but might be less complicated for you.

[Running] Headers and Footers are the only way in Word to have content repeat on multiple pages automatically.